# Static variable in static array

Tags: php

I'm trying to insert a static variable in an array like this :

```
static $datas = array(
    'link' => config::$link
);
```

But i'm having this error

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE, expecting T_STRING

I discovered [PHP doc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php) say that :

> Like any other PHP static variable, static properties may only be
>   initialized using a literal or constant; expressions are not allowed.
>   So while you may initialize a static property to an integer or array
>   (for instance), **you may not initialize it to another variable**, to a
>   function return value, or to an object.

But I'm sure there is a way to do that, any suggestion ?

Comment: Is `$datas` a static variable here? Otherwise this question makes little sense. Please provide a complete working code snippet that reproduces this error.

Comment: Usually this is worked-around with `static $var = null; if (is_null($var)) $var = array( /* actual dynamic initialization */ )`, which you might think could be safely implemented in PHP itself, but it isn't just because.

Comment: @deceze, yes $datas is also static

Comment: @Vivien Static variables and static properties are completely unrelated, this is a misleading reuse of a keyword in the PHP grammar.

Comment: Then you should show that properly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there is no workaround. `static` variables and properties can only be initialized with constant values. That means literals or constants. Variables, `static` or not, cannot be used, period. You have to assign a variable value later using procedural code somewhere.

Comment: Well, never give up hope... though in this case, I think it's safe to.