# Use array value inside the class

Tags: php

How to use array value inside the class? In this code i got an error:

```
<?php
class MyClass{
    public static $arr1 = [
        'key1' => "myString",
        'key2' => "aaaa"
    ];
    
    public static $arr2 = [
        'key' => self::$arr1['key1']    
    ];
    
}
```

But this code works normally:

```
<?php
class MyClass{
    public static $arr1 = [
        'key1' => "myString",
        'key2' => "aaaa"
    ];
}
$arr = [
    'key' => MyClass::$arr1['key1'] 
    
];
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Static variable in static array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12958411/static-variable-in-static-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may not use an expression as a default value. Only literals are allowed at compile time.

Initialize the dependend array in an initializer method instead.

```
<?php declare(strict_types = 1);

class MyClass
{
  public static array $arr1 = [
    'key1' => "myString",
    'key2' => "aaaa"
  ];

  public static array $arr2 = [];

  public static function initialize()
  {
    self::$arr2 = [
      'key' => self::$arr1['key1']
    ];
  }
}

MyClass::initialize();
```

If you do not intend to instanciate your class with `new MyClass()`, consider using namespaces instead of misusing classes for that purpose. Also have a look at the recently added `enum` support.